# Auto-create random ‘secure’ (obfuscated) url titles

Tags: channel-form, url-title, security

I have a site in which I'd like to achieve the following:

1. Provide a publicly accessible but obfuscated and hard to guess at
   URL to which a customer can be referred to, to submit some data via a
   **Channel Form** without them having to register and log in (the data
   they submit is personal to them but does not personally identify them).
2. Upon submission the entry is automatically closed so the form cannot be used again.

So what I'd ideally like is a way to **auto-generate unique URL Titles that are intrinsically hard to guess at**. Something like…

```
mydomain.com/segment/hyr6gDEGhyus
```

I guess I could achieve this with custom JavaScript in the CP but anyone got any other suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with last version (2.8.8) of [MX Title Control](https://github.com/MaxLazar/mx-title-control). You can add **{random_string}** tag into URL Title Pattern and get 10 characters random string.

**Hidden Configuration Variables**

```
$config['mx_random_string_length'] = "20";
$config['mx_random_string_pattern'] = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
```

Comment: Thanks, Max. That sounds exactly like what I need. Will give that a go. Assuming I can get that working, do you have a PayPal donation pot I can tip some money in to?

Answer (score 1):

Sure - create an extension using the [entry_submission_start hook](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/extension_hooks/api/channel_entries/index.html#entry-submission-start) and set your unique `url_title` there:

```
ee()->load->helper('string);
ee()->api_channel_entries->meta['url_title'] = random_string('alnum', 16);
```

Comment: Thanks, Derek. Max's answer below sounds more like my territory though.